# PHP - get data From meta value

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this record in data base row :

```
   a:2:
   {
     i:2;a:2:{s:6:"amount";d:150;s:11:"description";s:53:"value1";}
     i:3;a:2:{s:6:"amount";d:1800;s:11:"description";s:53:"value 2";}
   }
```

Is it Json or What exactly ?
And how can i extract data from it ?
I want to get each amount and description values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's serialized data. You can use `unserialize()` to turn it in to an array.

Comment: Thanks , but how can i access each data `$original_array=unserialize('...');
var_export($original_array);`

Comment: By using a `foreach()` loop. In your case, you have a multidimensional array (arrays within an array). There are tons of tutorials out there on that.